# Cannot truncate table 'Tabla' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola estoy tratando de truncar (`TRUNCATE`) una base de datos , pero tengo el problema de que algunas tablas están relacionadas entonces cuando intento tirarle el query me dice:

> Cannot truncate table 'Tabla' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Encontré que puedo inhabilitar las relaciones con :

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`

Al parecer tengo un error de sintaxis¿? 
Necesito quitar **TODA** la información de la base de datos (todas las tablas) sin alterar sus relaciones.
Estoy ocupando SQL Server Managment 2008

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Vas a hacerle truncate a esa tabla solamente, o todas?

Comment: A todas :D @sstan

Comment: Me dice que tengo error de sintaxis en **NOCHECK**

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40046/is-there-a-way-to-truncate-table-that-has-foreign-a-key

Comment: @gbianchi: No tengo tiempo ahora, pero si alguien quiere hacerlo, se aprecia.

Comment: @sstan listo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta respuesta es una copia textual de: [Is there a way to truncate table that has foreign a key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40046/is-there-a-way-to-truncate-table-that-has-foreign-a-key)

---

Necesitas borrar y recrear las claves, o esperar por el `DELETE` y que se vuelvan a rellenar. Deshabilitar la clave foránea temporariamente puede hacer mas rápido el `DELETE`, pero va a seguir sin dejarte hacer el truncate

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

-- borrar, rellenar, etc.

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

El fácil automatizar esto construyendo un SQL dinámico desde las tablas de metadatos, haciéndolo funcionar exactamente para las tablas que necesitas. Por ejemplo, esto lo hará para cada tabla que tenga una clave foránea y una columna `IDENTITY`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'SET NOCOUNT ON;';

;WITH s(t) AS
 (
   SELECT 
     QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_object_id)) 
     + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id))
  FROM sys.foreign_keys AS k
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.identity_columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = k.referenced_object_id
  )
  GROUP BY referenced_object_id
)
SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
  ALTER TABLE ' + t + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
  DELETE ' + t + ';
  DBCC CHECKIDENT(''' + t + ''', RESEED, 0) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
  ALTER TABLE ' + t + 'WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;'
FROM s;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Puede que la salida se vea truncada, pero esta es una limitación del PRINT (8K), el comando actual esta completo.

Comment: Hola ya he intentado lo de arribe, efectivamente me dice que ya efectó algunas tablas, me tira estó por ejemplo ** `  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Categories] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
  DELETE [dbo].[Categories];` ** pero cuando las checo siguen llenas y si trato de truncarlas, me tira el mismo error de la llave foranea ... D: